# Psycopg2 errors while inserting names contains 'into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have some data which i need to insert into my PostgreSQL database from another Postgres server.
So i'm using SSH tunnel for that and it is succesfull.But getting the below error while using the below script.

```
    12:02:16 INSERT INTO results ("position",product_name,url,company,price,crawler_date,searched_url,provider) 
SELECT 25,'Methylcobalamin Vitamin B-12 5000 mcg - Puritan's Pride - 30 Tabletten'
,'https://www.bodyandfit.com/Methylcobalamin-Vitamin-B-12-5000-mcg/p/11697','Body & Fit','5,90 ','2020-06-10 08:16:40.842252','https://www.google.com/search?q=Methylcobalamin','Google'
    12:02:16 database connection failed
    12:02:16 syntax error at or near "Pride"
    12:02:16 LINE 1: ...Methylcobalamin Vitamin B-12 5000 mcg - Puritan's Pride - 30...
```

Below is the script.

The data contains names with "'"& many symbols.How can i import all data without any errors like this and with same name

Any suggestions please?

```
          SQL_load="""SELECT * FROM results WHERE crawler_date ::DATE=CURRENT_DATE"""
          msql_ins="""INSERT INTO results 
     ("position",product_name,url,company,price,crawler_date,searched_url,provider) 
    SELECT """

            cur_local.execute(SQL_load)

            for row in cur_local:
              inser_query=msql_ins  + '' + row[0] + '' +',' 
                                    + '' + row[1] + '' +",'" 
                                    +row[2] + "','" 
                                    +row[3]+"','"
                                    +row[4]+"','"
                                    +str(row[5])
                                    +"','"+row[6]+"'
,'"+row[7]+"'"

               cur_dwh.execute(inser_query)
               print(inser_query)
               inser_query=''

            conn_dwh.commit()
```

Comment: Do not use string formatting of any kind including using `+` to construct SQL queries. It will lead to quoting and injection problems. Read https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries to find out how to do it right!

Comment: @KlausD.Could you please post it as an anwer.